# How to create composite key in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composite-key

I tried many ways but nothing work. I need to add a composite key to my table daily_deals_products. Which is developed in laravel and mysql.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDailyDealsProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('daily__deals__products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->timestamps();

      
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('daily__deals__products');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Schema::create("daily__deals__products", function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('product_id');
    $table->string('name');
});

DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE `daily__deals__products` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ,  `product_id` )');
```

Comment: Is this correct, $table->unique(['id','product_id']);?

Comment: it's composite key so no need to have a foreign key constraint in your scenario if i am not wrong

Comment: Thank you @Naveed Ali. Without using  use DB; its perfectly working. If use it, am getting errors. Sorry I couldn't upvote for your answer because I have less than 15 reputation. One more question, If I need to add another column, how can I go for it?@Naveed Ali

Comment: if this question helped you then you can accept this answer

Comment: you either need to refresh the migration using php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: If refresh data will lose. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, if you don't want to lose data then you have to create another migration for the same table and add that column in that new migration.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$table->primary(['id','product_id']);


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('daily__deals__products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(['id', 'product_id']);
        $table->unsignedInteger('id');
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');

    }
```

Comment: I got this error, when I use it. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `daily_deals_products` add primary key `daily_deals_products_id_product_id_primary`(`id`, `product_id`)) @Abdulmajeed